# Javascript/CSS- how to change the colour of a textarea scrollbar without a third party JS library?

Tags: javascript, css

I just want to change the colour of the scrollbar that appears when the text overflows the textarea to a darker colour, and I don't want to use jquery or any other libraries. How to do this in pure javascript/css for firefox and chrome?

Comment: completely impossible. Some things in the browser rendering scheme are not within the mighty reach of css. Im not serious by the way. js can do it obviously, but i do wonder why you don't want to use jquery

Comment: hi, im doing everyone "inline" inside a document, I don't want to reference any external files, even libraries saved locally.

Comment: Scrollbar styling is not covered in any CSS standard. YMMV, and leave it be (except if targeting say, iOS *only*) :D Any "re-implementation" of scroll-bars is bound to annoy someone or break some browser UX - don't break my two-finger scrolling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to get very far.

That being said, this is a recent post with a lot of talk about this subject in Webkit with a working demo.

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

You won't get a universal solution, but maybe you can get a partial one.